# AWS S3 cp does not download 40 GB file

Tags: download, amazon-web-services, cp, amazon-s3

I just uploaded a 40GB backup file from my linux EC2 machine to an S3 bucket. However when I want to download it the aws command ends with no message and nothing was copied.

Here is my command:

> aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FILE.tar.gz ./FILE.tar.gz

using "--dryrun" I get the following message:

> (dryrun) download: s3://BUCKET/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FILE.tar.gz to ./FILE.tar.gz

NOTE: I checked that the file does exists in S3 and that the disk I want to download to has enough space. As I could upload the same file I assume that the permissions of the Backup-User (IAM) are correct (Full Access to S3).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try and provide the full path to the file.  Before you do this verify the write permissions are correct.

Comment: What exit code do you get?

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right trail. The path was correct and there was no exit code or any other output! However, I had no right to writing the file to the directory I was in and without an error code I did not see that.

Answer (score 2):

@Ramhound had the right idea: I did not have the write permissions to the directory I wanted to download to and the `aws` command returns no error message or code (in this case).

Comment: I wish there was an error message.